# How can we detect custom screen category in android?

Tags: android, layout, categories

I would like to detect custom screen category in android being used in the particular activity,I would like to detect layout-sw640dp programatically,how can be this achieved.We can do the same for small,normal,large & xlarge layouts but I am not sure on this one,kindly help me on this.Thanks.

Comment: How is it different from others?

Comment: Its aimed for Galaxy S3 device,thats y..

Comment: My question was how is the detection logic different from others? (It isn't.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you need to do that. But, a quick walk-around is to use tag, for example:

In mdpi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/content_bg"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:id="@+id/name"
  android:tag="mdpi-xxx-yyy" >
```

In hdpi:

```
  android:id="@+id/name"
  android:tag="hdpi-xxx-yyy" >
```

Then, read tag from your code for R.id.name.

---

Comment: View v = (View) findViewById(R.id.name); v.getTag();

Answer (score 1):

`sw640dp` just means the smallest available dimension is at least 640dp. This is based off the available layout space for an activity, not the actual resolution of the device. So you can calculate this based off the dimensions of your root layout in the activity:

```
int density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int widthDp = rootView.getWidth() / density;
int heightDp = rootView.getHeight() / density;
if(widthDp >= 640 || heightDp >= 640) {
    // qualifies for sw640dp
}
else {
    // does not qualify for sw640dp
}
```

In the case of the Galaxy S3, it's resolution is 1280x720, which is 640x360 converted to dp units. Since `sw` pertains to the available dimensions of the *layout*, not the resolution, I'm guessing it would *not* qualify for `sw640dp` since system decorations, such as the status bar, would reduce your layout's available height.

Comment: this can get dimension, but can't get other configuration, e.g. drawable-en-rUS-long-hdpi-v9

Comment: @Calvin Correct, but that wasn't the question. OP wanted to know how to detect `layout-sw640dp`