# I can not create layout-sw640dp folder

Tags: android, layout

I want different layout for my devices. I create folder `layout-sw640dp` and put into it `my.xml`.  I have my.xml in folder `layout` but they different. If i start application on `Samsung Galaxy Note 4 (640dpi)` i want see my.xml from `layout-sw640dp` but i see my.xml from `layout`.

Comment: In order for a phone to take the layout from layout-sw640dp it has to have that resolution. I think Samsung Galaxy Note 4 will just take the resources from layout-xxhdpi if available or layout if it doesn't exist.

Comment: You can also have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15426571/1067744)

Comment: I'm writing this phone has the desired resolution

Comment: @ip696 please mention the device name/dpi/resolution of the said.